# SvelteKit.next Static Site Adapter Pages Return 404 on Refresh

Tags: javascript, routes, svelte, sveltekit, static-site

I know this can't be that hard, but Googling isn't turning up any answers. I'm using the SvelteKit static site adapter, and it's building the site, but the build file structure is:

```
root
  - _app
  - faviceon.png
  - index.html
  - secondpage.html
```

But, when you click on the navigation items to take you to the secondary page, the URL is: `url.com/secondpage` rather than `url.com/secondpage.html`. I'm assuming the generated JS is doing the routing here, but if you input the url directly or refresh the second page, it returns a 404.

I know this has to be a config issue, but I've tried tons of variations, and the build stays the same. This is my `svelte.config.js` file:

```
// import adapter from "@sveltejs/adapter-auto";
import adapter from "@sveltejs/adapter-static";
import preprocess from "svelte-preprocess";

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    // Consult https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-preprocess
    // for more information about preprocessors
    preprocess: preprocess({
        scss: {
            prependData: `@import './src/lib/scss/style.scss';`,
        },
    }),

    kit: {
        adapter: adapter({
            // default options are shown. On some platforms
            // these options are set automatically — see below
            pages: "build",
            assets: "build",
            fallback: null,
            precompress: false,
            trailingSlash: 'always',
        }),
    },
};

export default config;
```

I initially didn't have the trailingSlash param, but the few sort of related things in docs and on StackOverflow made it seem like that might affect the routing code generation.

Anyway, let me know if you need any other code samples from me, or if just not seeing the forest for the trees.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I found the same situation, I found out that I should put a line in src/routes/+layout.js

```
export const trailingSlash = 'always'
```

Comment: I just spent some time trying to fix this myself, and I want to point out that this MUST be in `+layout.js` (or `.ts`) and doesn't work if it's put in a `script` tag in `+layout.svelte`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when there are multiple pages, the adapter-static generates several html files and expects all links to be static. The routes, even when they are static, are being treated by static-adapter as dynamic and it complains when `prerender: true` is set.

The adapter-static has two distinct modes of operation: SPA and prerendering. When there are several routes, both the `npm run dev` and `npm run preview` works as intended, but once built, the static routing falls to the web server who cannot found the page without the `.html`.

I found a workaround to avoid converting the site to a SPA: Installing a url rewrite mechanism as a middleware in order to add the `.html` extension that the static server is expecting in the compiled site.

For Nginx static server the solution is a url rewrite configuration as explained here: https://www.codesmite.com/article/clean-url-rewrites-using-nginx
For other servers, the solution should be very similar

Comment: For Apache .htaccess, this will cover it: 
```RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\./]+)/?$ $1.html [QSA]```

Comment: Any advice for how to handle this when the site is served by Cloudflare Pages?

Comment: For Cloudflare, there is a rewrite rule mechanism explained here: https://developers.cloudflare.com/rules/transform/url-rewrite/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem for prerendered dynamic routes throwing 404 on refresh or direct links.

In my case I had a `/archive/[slug]` route and further dynamic subroutes, all marked as `prerender=true`.

However, the problem was that these routes were then not included "in the manifest" according to the [prerender page options](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/page-options).  You have to use `prerender='auto'` for the dynamic routes to be included.  TBH I don't understand why `true` works different than `auto`, but this solved the 404 on refresh problem for me.